# generating unique random numbers with aes

Tags: random, aes

I m studiying the possibility of generating unique random number with AES-128. When the input is unique, the output is also unique after executing the AES algorithm. The execution of the ares algorithm results a kind of vector let's note by Rand[].
Let's note the pseudo-random number pingOffset = (Rand[0] + Rand[1]x 256) modulo Period (the parameter "period indicates a periodicity fixed number for every pingOffset generation).
Can I confirm so that the pingOffset is unique for every unique input. (The input is unique beacause it consist of a device address which is unique).

Comment: Generating random numbers by using AES is not only possible, but actually commonly done, when using the CTR mode of operation.

Comment: Yes, but I m asking about the unicity of the random number generated with AES

Comment: You are apparently using only two bytes of the AES result, and then further reducing the output range according to the `Period` parameter that you didn't give the actual value of.  You are *guaranteed* to have duplicate outputs by the time the number of inputs equals `Period`; in fact duplicates become *likely* by the time you reach the square root of `Period` (see "birthday paradox" for details).